# Linking or joining data in MS Acess to shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, spatial-database, ms-access

I am creating a spatial database for five buildings for a project that I am working on. I have spatial data in the form of a shapefile and attribute data in Microsoft Access(with a table and queries). There is a common field "TOTAL_AREA(m.sq)" for both spatial and attribute data.

I would like to join both attribute and spatial data in QGIS to create the spatial database. I tried to load the MS Access Database using ODBC Data sources but nothing showed.

Is there a way to do this without using ODBC?

I am using a Windows10 Operating system with QGIS 3.4, 64 bit.

Comment: From memory, you must align 32 or 64 bits : MS Access 32bits with ODBC 32bits with QGIS 32 bits. Windows, from config panel show just one version of ODBC configuration tool, you must search manually the other version.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response. I have been able to import the access database now. Do you know how I can join both data sets? And also, do you know how I can show the queries in the access database?

Comment: You can join your shapefile and MS Access table in QGIS with project relations. Maybe there is a spatial extension for MS Access ... My first though is to convert geometry into WKT and load it into QGIS, in QGIS you can create a geometry generator with the WKT, but I don't know how to modify geometry simply.

Comment: I have researched about the project relations, but I realized that I have only one table( which has one-to-one relationship). I have searched a lot but couldn't find how to create this kind of relationship with project relations in QGIS? Do you think it is okay to use attribute join to join my shapefile and access table using the common field in both datasets? Will that create the spatial database?

Comment: For a great answer, I think you need to expose your goals with details, no one can answer you with good advices without.